# Windows domain user as service logon user

Tags: windows-server-2012, service

I need to set a domain user as service logon settings. This works if I run the service manually, but at windows bootup the service start fails because it "cannot find the user", maybe because the network/domain controller is not available yet. How can I force it to remember user credentials to use this service with auto-start or in offline mode?

Answer (score 1):

In the service console (services.msc), double click on the specific service, logon tab, select "this user" and enter the correct credential.

It should be sufficient, unless some group policy remove the "logon as a service" right (see [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/it-it/library/cc794944(v=ws.10).aspx) for more information)

Comment: That user is set with logon as service, what does it means? Can be connected with my issue?

Answer (score 0):

To overcome this issue it may be necessary to set the service startup type to “Delayed Start.”

This will give the network stack enough time to come online before trying to authenticate with a domain account.

Remember, this can be an issue if the DC ever becomes unavailable. The service will shutdown and fail to run within a short period of time. So redundancy is key if it is a critical service.

Comment: In this case the service is Apache, I want a domain user to manage permissions to all fileshares to web apps. I think that this service should run also without domain controllers.